# What is the earliest point in which you can get 6 stars?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

At the beginning it's not possible to get more than 4 stars. When is it? Is it after a mission in the storyline or can something else unlock it?

Comment: cheats can unlock it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start with 4, as you noted. Unlock the next island and you can get up to 5. Unlock the third island and you can get 6 stars.. It has been a bit too long for me to remember what plot quests this event happens at however.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get 5 stars after completing the mission *Doberman*, which is before you unlock the second area.